# How to check if the form is edit/view/create form in a template for Django admin

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-admin

I want to customize the view only template in Django admin and want to add custom CSS class if the user opens the view only form (for example class="test_class").

I tried this to change the class for edit form so I can use the default one for add and change templates: [Can I tell if a form is an 'edit' form in a template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13398677/can-i-tell-if-a-form-is-an-edit-form-in-a-template/13398702) but it doesn't work. I don't see my custom class when I inspect the form.

I want to know if there is a more "cleaner" solutions than this: [How to add css class to Django admin form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46580638/how-to-add-css-class-to-django-admin-form)

For example (this is a pure guess) something like this in change_form.html:
`<form {% if form.is_change_form %} class="test_class" {% endif %}`